# Netty sending 2 packets instead of one

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I'm making my first steps with netty and I'm wondering about the following behaviour of netty:

When i use the following Handler:

```
public class SimpleServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf inBuffer = (ByteBuf) msg;

    String received = inBuffer.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date()) + " Server received: " + received);

    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Hello " + received, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

And I then send a TCP packet with "Packet Sender" I get three packets

the first is from the "packet sender" to the server,
the second is the response from the server (so something like "Hello testtest")
and then .. and I don't know where this packet comes from: 
**a third one from the server to the "packet sender", without any content**

My Server java is:

```
public class MainNettyApplicationServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        serverBootstrap.group(group);
        serverBootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        serverBootstrap.localAddress(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.2", 11111));

        serverBootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleServerHandler());
            }
        });
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind().sync();
        System.out.println("Server started.");
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: An ACK segment?

Comment: What TCP flags are present on both packets?

Comment: can you please tell me which tool is needed to see the TCP flags?